# Log in to skype via a program?

Tags: c#, skype

I have three skype accounts (two for work, one for personal). When I restart my computer, only the last one I logged in with comes up. You can, once skype starts up, start another skype window by typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary

However, you have to manually log in. I want to make a program that when I click starts three skype windows and logs in. I know how to *start* skype multiple times, but I don't know how to log in short of using `SendKeys`

Comment: Instead of "rolling your own" why not just use an existing (free) application to do this? http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: Because I don't want to send keys. I want it to just happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some other, less “official” command line parameters are:
>
> "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /username:your user name /password:your password

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/CLI-commands/td-p/412397